# Null conditional operator and LINQ

Tags: c#

There is my code (it is used in net core project):

```
 var list = await user.RelatedEntityCanBeNull?.ToListAsync();
```

It throws NullReferenceException if RelatedEntityCanBeNull is null for user. Why doesn't the expression return null?

Comment: Talking about accessing `user` properties, shouldn't it be `user?.RelatedEntityCanBeNull?.ToListAsync();`? You access `user` without null-conditional operator, and it is null, and it gives an error. However, I am not sure how `await` does work with `null` tasks.

Comment: I suspect it's because you're awaiting a null `Task` here.

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev, I checked user explicitly. It's not null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Try to use `user.RelatedEntityCanBeNull.GetValueOrDefault().ToListAsync()` (if available)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The await operator expects an awaitable `Task` object. The Null conditional operator returns `null` and `await null` results in a `NullReferenceException`.

You have to change your code to

```
List list = null;
if (user?.RelatedEntityCanBeNull != null)
   list = await user.RelatedEntityCanBeNull.ToListAsync();
```

or

```
var list = user?.RelatedEntityCanBeNull == null ? null : await user.RelatedEntityCanBeNull.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: or `await (user.RelatedEntityCanBeNull?.ToListAsync() ?? Task.FromResult<...>(null));` to be more concise.

Comment: @stop-cran your decision let to escape manual null -check even when there is long chain properties in expression like this: user.First?.Second?... great